# Cannot get Yahoo option data using Remote Data Access of Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am trying to download Yahoo option data using the remote data access function of Pandas, I installed Anaconda on my laptop and launch ipython-qtconsole. I ran the following commands and got error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'month', do I miss a module? If so, how can I find it?

```
from pandas.io.data import Options

aapl = Options('aapl', 'yahoo')

data = aapl.get_all_data()
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 data = aapl.get_all_data()
>
> C:\Personal\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\data.pyc in
>   get_all_data(self, call, put)    1109     1110             for month
>   in months:
>   -> 1111                 m2 = month.month    1112                 y2 = month.year    1113
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'month'

Comment: Works for me; what does `print(pd.__version__)` show?

Comment: mine shows 0.14.1. Does that mean I need to upgrade it? I installed Anaconda

Comment: To update pandas. Run: `conda update pandas`